# How can I leave a Lua function closure in a tail call?

Tags: c, lua

In Lua, a [C closure](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#4.4) is created with a function pointer and additional values (*upvalues*) that will be available when the closure is invoked.

In my application I use this feature to pass a getter methods table to the `__index` metamethod. If the key exists as method, it will then be invoked, passing its original parameters. If I invoke the function directly, then somehow the upvalues are still available to the callee and thus executing in the same function closure.

Is it possible to leave the function closure or somehow erase the upvalues? The goal is to reduce unnecessary exposure of upvalues without introducing significant overhead.

Here is a MWE (42 lines) that demonstrates the issue with a TODO highlighting the issue. It currently prints `upvalue: 42` twice. The expected result is one `upvalue: 42` and another `upvalue: 0` (for an invalid value).

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lua.h>

static void *allocfn(void *ud, void *ptr, size_t osize, size_t nsize) {
    if (nsize == 0) {
        free(ptr);
        return NULL;
    } else {
        return realloc(ptr, nsize);
    }
}

static int myfunc(lua_State *L) {
    lua_CFunction cfunc = lua_tocfunction(L, 1);
    printf("myfunc called with %p\n", cfunc);
    printf("upvalue: %d\n", (int)lua_tointeger(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
    // TODO how to drop upvalue (tail call, leaving the closure)?
    return cfunc(L);
}

static int otherfunc(lua_State *L) {
    printf("otherfunc called with %p\n", lua_tocfunction(L, 1));
    printf("upvalue: %d\n", (int)lua_tointeger(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));
    return 0;
}

int main() {
    lua_State *L = lua_newstate(allocfn, NULL);

    /* Create closure for myfunc with upvalue 42. */
    lua_pushinteger(L, 42);
    lua_pushcclosure(L, myfunc, 1);

    /* Argument 1 for myfunc. */
    lua_pushcclosure(L, otherfunc, 0);

    /* Invoke myfunc(otherfunc) with "42" in its closure. */
    lua_call(L, 1, 0);

    lua_close(L);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Call the function through Lua, instead of calling the C function directly:

```
static int myfunc(lua_State *L) {
    // cfunc still used for printing here
    lua_CFunction cfunc = lua_tocfunction(L, 1);
    printf("myfunc called with %p\n", cfunc);
    printf("upvalue: %d\n", (int)lua_tointeger(L, lua_upvalueindex(1)));

    // call the C function as if it was a Lua function
    int stackSizeBefore = lua_gettop(L);
    lua_call(L, 0, LUA_MULTRET);
    return lua_gettop(L) - stackSizeBefore;
}
```

(note: untested code)

Comment: Wouldn't this simply create a new closure? What about the return values (this does compile btw, `lua_call` is void). In my case I can probably be sure that there is always zero or one return values, but can this be generalized? (See also updated requirement on preservation of arguments via the stack)

Comment: @Lekensteyn Updated for return values; I'd assume in this example you don't want to use the same arguments, since that would just pass the function to itself which is pointless.

Comment: Thanks, but I do actually want to pass the original parameters. In the real case I have `metatable.__newindex(obj, key, value)`, it should invoke `setter(obj, value)` where `setter` is found via the upvalue. The `lua_gettop(L)` before/after suggestion is good to find the returned values, but if I change it to preserve params (`lua_call(0, lua_gettop(L), LUA_MULTRET)`), then it errors out with: `lapi.c:895: lua_callk: Assertion '((nargs+1) < (L->top - L->ci->func)) && "not enough elements in the stack"' failed`. Any idea?

Comment: To pass N parameters you need to push the function, then the N parameters. I suggest using lua_gettop at the start of the function to get the number of parameters, then push the function you want to call, then push all the parameters again.

Comment: Hmm, that seems to result in more overhead than desired. I think your approach is the best that can be done to hide the upvalues. There does not seem to be a way to "pop" the function closure otherwise, right?

Answer (score 0):

Lua upvalues are really restricted to a closure, you cannot access upvalues in other closures. A closure is entered by invoking a C closure (created via `lua_pushcclosure`) or by invoking a Lua closure (created via a ["block"](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#3.5), `lua_load`, etc).

To enter a new closure in C, use the [`lua_call`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_call) family of functions as described in [immibis' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39821499/427545).

Another idea would be "erasing" the upvalues from the current scope. This will not have the desired result since upvalues are bound to a closure, so once you "clear" it (by setting the value to `nil`), it will persist to the next invocation (this is what the [Programming in Lua documentation means by equivalence to a static variable](https://www.lua.org/pil/27.3.3.html)).

A new question arises, would it somehow be possible to overwrite the existing closure by calling another function from the C function? The answer is no. When a closure is invoked, it ultimately calls `luaD_precall`. This C function basically creates a new "function scope" on the current Lua state, then invokes the C function pointer:

```
int luaD_precall (lua_State *L, StkId func, int nresults) {
  lua_CFunction f;
  CallInfo *ci;
  // ...
  switch (ttype(func)) {
    // ...
    case LUA_TCCL: {  /* C closure */
      f = clCvalue(func)->f;/* obtain C function pointer */
      // ...
      ci = next_ci(L);      /* now 'enter' new function ("nested scope") */
      // ...
      n = (*f)(L);          /* do the actual call to a C function */
      // ...
      luaD_poscall(L, L->top - n);
      return 1;             /* not Lua code, do not invoke Lua bytecode */
```

Only after returning from the function, it will move to the previous "function scope":

```
int luaD_poscall (lua_State *L, StkId firstResult) {
  // ...
  CallInfo *ci = L->ci;
  // ...
  L->ci = ci = ci->previous;  /* back to caller ("function scope") */
```

Unless it is somehow possible to change the program counter to some custom function, you will not be able to invoke your function outside the current closure. Furthermore, you will have a new problem: the function will now execute in the parent closure. The two options at this point is to accept that the second function simply executes in the current scope, or to create a new scope.

A similar question in Lua is whether to reuse a scope:

```
function myfunc()
    print("myfunc")
    print("otherfunc")
end
```

or to create a new one:

```
function myfunc()
    print("myfunc")
    do  -- note: new Lua closure created
        print("otherfunc")
    end
end
```

To reduce overhead, simply reuse the current closure ("function scope"). If hiding local upvalues is important (to prevent accidental modification), then invoke the C closure. In any case, you cannot directly access other upvalues via pseudoindexes obtained from [`lua_upvalueindex`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_upvalueindex), this would instead require a query via [`lua_getupvalue`](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.2/manual.html#lua_getupvalue).